Comparing the size of two integrals; integrands are algebraic functions weighted by Gaussians
I have two integrals that I can compute numerically in Mathematica.
$$ I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dy  \left(1+x^2+y^2 -\sqrt{(1+x^2+y^2)^2-4y^2} \right) e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}} \approx  4.30$$
$$J = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dy  \left(2+2x+x^2+y^2 -\sqrt{(2+2x+x^2+y^2)^2-4y^2} \right) e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}} \ \approx 3.54$$
Is there a nice way to see that $I>J$ without numerics?

This problem arose in trying to answer this MO question; these expressions are expectation values of the minimum eigenvalue of two different matrices. In the language of that question, this is for $A=\text{diag}(1,0)$ and $b=(1,0)$. Proving $I>J$ will prove a counterexample to the hypothesis in that question. While numerics is likely good enough for the purposes of that question, I'm curious if there is a nice analytical way to see $I>J$; it's hard for me to see it even on an intuitive basis.
